# Zip folder dated yesterday and move to network location

Tags: powershell, zip

I need a script to run every day and zip the folder that was created the previous day.
I then need the zipped version to be moved to a network location.
I was thinking of using 7zip to do the zipping as this is installed on the servers but I'm open to alternatives if there is a better way\method\tool.

Here are some additional details.

The folders to zip are named in this format:

```
20171228  
20171229  
20171230
```

I need to move the zipped version from

```
D:\usr\sap\gkretail\ucon\dataexchange\export_channel\results\export\EXPORT_SUCCESS
```

To

```
SOL000483\domain.com\GK_Transaction_Archive
```

Here's what I've managed to coble together so far but it fails at the `$yesterdaysfolder` variable I think.

```powershell
$pathTo7zip = "C:\Users\gustasoh\Desktop\7z1701-extra\x64\7za.exe"
$sourcefolder = "C:\Users\gustasoh\Desktop\7z1701-extra\x64"
$yesterdaysfolder = "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')"
$Destination1 = "C:\Users\gustasoh\Desktop\ZIPPED\"

C:\Users\gustasoh\Desktop\7z1701-extra\x64\7za.exe a -tzip *.7zip $sourcefolder\$yesterdaysfolder

# Check destination path
if (Test-Path $Destination1) {
    # then copy
    Copy-Item $Source *.7zip $Destination1
}
```

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far (show your code), and what *particular* problem (in your code) do you need help with?

Comment: I know how to perform the command line zip function.  7za a -tzip 20171227.7zip 20171227  What I don't know is how to target only the folder with the previous days date.

Comment: `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')`

Comment: Okay so I've managed to coble this script together however it's failing at my $yesterdaysfolder variable

Comment: Remove the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get my code working but I wanted to thank everyone here for their time and assistance.  In the Spirit of sharing I thought I would post it here in case it helps somebody else out.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'

$Source = 'C:\7z1701-extra\x64'
$Destination = 'C:\7z1701-extra\x64\ZIPPED'

$d = (get-date).adddays(-1).tostring('yyyyMMdd')
$SourceFolder = Join-Path -Path $Source -ChildPath $d

Write-Verbose "Archiving $SourceFolder"
[IO.Compression.Zipfile]::CreateFromDirectory($SourceFolder, "$Destination\$d.zip")

Move-Item -Path $Destination\*.zip -Destination \\server.domain.cloud\GK_Transaction_Archive
```